# When creating defaultTextAttributes within Swift, I am unable to set the text fill color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Right now for a course I am working on we are supposed to create a meme editor. Basically what I want is text to appear within a textfield on top of a picture. The outline of the text should be black, the inside should be white, and the background of the text field should be clear. However, no matter what I do, I cannot set the text color to something different than the background color. I've tried setting the foreground within the text attributes, the text color within the storyboard, and the text color programatically. No matter what, my text fill matches the background, so as of right now, it's always clear. I want it to be white. Please help!

Here is where I set the text attributes:

```
let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = 
[NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor.black,   
NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,    
NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-
CondensedBlack", size: 36)!, NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: 4.0]
```

Here is where I set properties of the textFields. The rest of the properties are being set so I know the way the function is being called and the way the text fields are being referenced isn't the issue.

```
func setPropertiesOfTextField(_ textField : UITextField){
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textField.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes
    textField.textColor = UIColor.white
    textField.textAlignment = .center
    textField.delegate = textFieldDelegate
}
```